# Suddenly dotnet core can't build my project on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, ubuntu-18.04

My home machine runs Rider on Ubuntu 18.04 for .net core development. I use a near identical setup on my work machine.

Suddenly i can't build my .net core project at home. It still builds fine at work, but for some reason it keeps failing on my home machine with:

```
The imported project "/code/slndir/projectname/obj/projectname.csproj.*.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  /snap/dotnet-sdk/44/sdk/2.2.401/Current/Microsoft.Common.props
```

Stuff I've tried includes:

- confirming that the file does in fact exist after build
- reinstalling rider.
- copied the settings directory from my work computer's home directory to my home computer's home directory
- deleting the settings directory from my home computer's home directory then reinstalling rider
- reinstalled .net core sdk 2x with (snap and apt)
- reinstalled mono

The projects loading means msbuild is loading, what the heck is wrong?
This feels like I'm using the wrong tooling. What am I missing?

---Update

I've also tried building this from the cli. Something is amiss.

Comment: So you can build your project from command line and can not from Rider? But Rider loads your projects at the same time?

Comment: No. It doesn't build at all. I think I'm mistaken in tagging this with rider. on closer examination it might be msbuild.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this with a simple console app? Or narrow it down to a minimum example? Please also add `dotnet --info` output. Which shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using bash. will try to suss out dotnet --info when i get home.